# Taxonomy.php not working for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a custom post type with name services and added taxonomy with name catservice. I named my taxonomy file taxonomy-catservice.php and its not working, I also tried it by renaming it to taxonomy-services but it also didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without see the code from you posttype and you custom taxonomy.
But the best tip I can give you ehre is to check you custom_post code where you create it.
and see so you have included that you custom post type has included you taxonomy.
For example see this code:

```
$args = array(
            'label'                 => __( 'CUstom post type', 'domain' ),
            'description'           => __( 'description', 'domain' ),
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
            'taxonomies'            => array( 'custom_taxonomy'),
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => false,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'rewrite'               => false,
            'capability_type'       => 'page',
        );
        register_post_type( 'custom_post_type', $args );
```

And the important thing there is to check that the key `taxonomies` is there and it you custom taxnonomy name is there.

That or you can do it from your custom taxonomy when you register it like this:

```
register_taxonomy( 'custom_taxonomy', array( 'custom_post_type_name' ), $args );
```

you see the second param in that function gets an array with you custom post type name in it.

Hope this might give you some help :)

**EDIT:**

After I did run a test with that plugin, so when I create my Custom Taxonomy after I created the Custom post type, I could choose what post types that custom taxonomy should be linked to. See image below:

[image]

And that worked for me, so that taxonomy is now displayed add avaible to add to my custom post type

Comment: i created it using CPT UI

Comment: did you create both the taxonomy and the the custom post type thru this?

Comment: yes i used this to create both custom post type and taxonomy

Comment: so what was your file name?

Comment: I have no files for it, because I didn't exported them. I just created them thru the plugin inside WordPress. And it worked out of the box.
If you exported them out you need to check so thoose files are included for example in your functions.php. Your files will not automaticly be included

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, this is working on my end, Also update the permalink after adding the code in function.php.

```
$labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Services', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Service', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Services', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Service', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Service', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Service', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Service', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Service', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Services', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Services', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Services:', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No services found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No services found in Trash.', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( 'Service Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives'              => _x( 'Service archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into services', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this services', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter services list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Services list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list'            => _x( 'Services list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Services', 'domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'description', 'domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'catservice'),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => false,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'services', $args );
 
    // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Service Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Service Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Service Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Service Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Service Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Service Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Service Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Service Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Service Category Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate service categories with commas', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove service categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used service categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No service categories found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Service Categories', 'textdomain' ),
    );
 
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'catservice' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'catservice', array( 'services' ), $args );
```

Note: Update permalink from the settings options.